# How to know when function javascript has done with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My application has one button that call a function inside a controller. 
How to know, when function has done/complete, using directive?

I'd to trigger a function after this processing in my directive.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your question

Comment: If you call a function inside the controller, the controller knows when it's done and can set a flag on the `$scope` to trigger showing an element or a directive, for example, with `ng-if`

Answer (score 0):

As New Dev commented, it makes more sense to handle it within the controller, but if you must put it in a directive, then I think you would need to define your own ngClick directive, that wraps the function call. Something like this should work:

```
app.directive("ngWrapClick", function ($parse) {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var clickFn = $parse(attr.ngWrapClick);
    element.bind("click", function () {
      clickFn(scope);
      // function complete
    })
  }
});
```

and use this instead of ngClick in your button:

```
<button ng-wrap-click="doSomething()">
```

Remember that doSomething could be asynchronous and could return before it has actually finished processing. Using promises or callbacks would be more appropriate in that scenario.